# Alternative to the % symbol for commenting code?

Tags: comments, sourcecode

I know that `%` can be used to make LaTeX ignore an entire line. However, suppose that I want LaTeX to skip 50 consecutive lines of code, is there a better way to do this than inserting `%` 50 times in front of each line?

Comment: This depends a lot on what you want to do; look on the site for the `comment` package.

Comment: @gernot Why should nested conditional bother?

Comment: I usually write `\def\useless{` at the beginning and `}` at the end...

Comment: These solutions work like charms, thank you very much!

Comment: Your editor, if well configured, can probably add a `%` at the beginning of every line of a selection?

Comment: `\iffalse...\fi`. If you use a TeX-aware editor, then there is probably a shortcut that allows you to add `%` signs in front of many lines at once, and also to remove them again at the same time.

Comment: @egreg I don't know. Maye because I'm pessimistic or extra-cautious? ;-)

Comment: @Bernard I use TeXstudio. I believe it should be possible but I've never tried it yet (not like I know how though).

Comment: I don't know well enough TeXstudio to say. I'm pretty sure it's possible with `Emacs`, and I can do (and undo) it in WinEdt.